Deletion of past data from the Flink Dynamic Table
I have access logs data of the users that keep on coming. Dailye we get near about 2 million access logs of the user. One user can access more than once also, so our problem statement is to keep the track of user access with entry_time(first access in a day) and exit_time(last access in a day).
I have already prepared the flinkjob to do it which will calculate this information on runtime via streaming job.
Just for the sale of understanding, this is data we will be calculating
user_name, location_name, entry_time, entry_door, exit_time, exit_door, etc.
By applying the aggregation on the current day data I can fetch the day wise user arrival information.
But the problem is I want to delete the past day data from this flink dynamic table since past day records are not requried. And as I mentined, since we daily get 2 million records, so if we won't delete the past day records then data will keep on adding to this flink table and with time, process will keep on getting slower since data is increasing at rapid rate.
So what to do to delete the past day data from the flink dynamic table since I only want to calculate the user arrival of the current day?
FYI, I am getting this access logs data in the kafka, and from the kafka data I am applying the aggregation and then sending the aggregation data to another kafka, from there I am saving it to opensearch.
I can share the code also if needed.
Do let me know how to delete the past day data from the flink dynamic table
I have tried with state TTL clear up, but it didn't help as I can see the past day data is still there.
